# How to add "App Open Ads" of admob in react native android app?

Tags: react-native, admob

How to add "App Open Ads" in react native app android?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a library from GreedyGame for react native apps. This currently has app open ads integrated. The documentation is also updated.You can check out the docs [here](https://console.greedygame.com/docs/latest/react-native/setup-sdk) . You will need to sign up and get an appId to work. You can sign up [here](https://greedygame.com/sdk-x?utm_source=stackoverflow_answer&utm_medium=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=app_open_ads_answer)

I work at GreedyGame.